# Ativar um campo de input de acordo com um enum

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Tenho um enum de escolaridade se caso o usuário selecionar o nível de escolaridade como Superior incompleto ou completo quero que apareça um campo para inserir qual é o curso

Como posso fazer isso ?

```
    <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.GrauEscolaridade, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.GrauEscolaridade, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GrauEscolaridade, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>



   public enum GrauEscolaridade{
        [Display(Name = "Superior incompleto ")]
        SuperiorIncompleto = 15,
        [Display(Name = "Superior Completo")]
        SuperiorCompleto = 16
}
```

Comment: você poderia postar parte do que já fez até agora, isso facilitaria ao tentarmos ajudá-lo.

Comment: Postei a estrutura que tenho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fazer uma alteração no seu dropdownListFor:
Adicionado "@id = 'nome_do_meu_dropDownList'"

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.GrauEscolaridade, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.GrauEscolaridade, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @id = "nome_do_meu_dropDownList" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GrauEscolaridade, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Colocar no fim da sua view(Html)

```
<input type="text" name="NomeCurso">


// Referência ao framework jquery CDN
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#NomeCurso').hide();

    $("#nome_do_meu_dropDownList").change(function () {

       // 15 e 16 são o Id do Superior completo ou superior incompleto
       if ($("#nome_do_meu_dropDownList").val() == '15' || $("#nome_do_meu_dropDownList").val() == '16') {
           $('#NomeCurso').show(); // Exibe o campo text para digitar o nome do curso
       } else {
           $('#NomeCurso').hide(); // Oculta o campo nome do curso
       }

   });

});

</script>
```

Comment: Poderia dar um exemplo de como eu usaria no meu código ?

Comment: Resposta atualizada.